# Component Based AppId Name

Tags: inno-setup, app-id

Is it possible to create a unique AppId name based on component selected to install.  I have an Add that installs State specific components for each state, only one state can be selected to install at a time.  If I could either prefix or suffix the GUID with the component (state initials), it should then be possible to uninstall each state independently. I've tried the below but does not seem to do the trick.

```
function GetAppId(Value: string): string;
    begin  
        Result := {WizardSelectedComponents} + '{{244A887F-F3DC-4B8D-B0F8-548A90464CEF}';
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, for however many components you want a different ID for:

```
function GetAppId(Value: string): string;
var
  strResult: String;
begin
  if IsComponentSelected('ComponentName1') then
    begin
      strResult := '{244A887F-F3DC-4B8D-B0F8-548A90464CEF}';
    end
  else if IsComponentSelected('ComponentName2') then
    begin
      strResult := '{A0A115ED-45E5-4DC7-A73A-3E8046CA4478}';
    end;
end;
```

Comment: There's no need to escape constants when you are assigning a directive value at runtime (escaping is needed for compiler). This code would actually produce a GUID with doubled braces (but who knows, maybe that was intended). Also, don't forget to initialize the `Result` variable.